# Magento 1.9 Where is original price saved in order tables?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, special-price

If a customer bought a product with **special price** (catalog price rule), the **special price** will be saved in *sales_flat_order_item* table. I wonder if the **original price** is also saved in this table? If so, in which database field it is saved in? I've looked through the whole table and I couldn't find where the original price is.

---

I found a column called Original Price. But it saves the **special price** as the original price.

Comment: you have found it if you have checked the same table

Comment: Do you mind to tell me which column in this table the original price is saved in? I've look at each column by now. it display the same price (special price) in all columns.